# Windows10 failed to install python-lib :crfnet from github using "python setup.py build_ext"

Tags: python

I want to install a python-lib named crfnet which is a deep-learning library whose environment is: Windows10 CUDA11.1 Tensorflow2.4.4 keras2.4.4.
I have installed all of the packages needed, but when I run "python setup.py build_ext --inplace" in the windows shell, it raised an error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module found named crfnet".
Here are the details that the shell displayed:

```
(crfnet) PS D:\Naca\Deep_learning_Reproduction> python .\train_crfnet.py --config .\configs\default.cfg

Using TensorFlow backend.
2022-04-05 18:30:00.045863: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\train_crfnet.py", line 29, in <module>
    import crfnet  # noqa: F401
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crfnet'
```

How should I solve it?
thank you very much!

I have tried "python setup.py build_ext" and "python setup.py install" and so on, but it remains to be the same problem.